# Remove "server" header from Envoy Proxy responses

Tags: envoyproxy

I'm currently trying to configure an Envoy route to remove the `server` header placed there by Envoy.

I've tried using the `response_headers_to_remove`[1] field. It works for many fields (`x-content-type-options`, `x-powered-by`, etc), but not with `server`.

I'm using Envoy Proxy 1.7.0.

[1] https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#config-route-v3-route

Answer (score 2):

I found that this is possible.

The HTTPConnectionManager has a setting called [ServerHeaderTransformation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3/http_connection_manager.proto#enum-extensions-filters-network-http-connection-manager-v3-httpconnectionmanager-serverheadertransformation):

```
OVERWRITE
(DEFAULT) ⁣Overwrite any Server header with the contents of server_name.

APPEND_IF_ABSENT
⁣If no Server header is present, append Server server_name If a Server header is present, pass it through.

PASS_THROUGH
⁣Pass through the value of the server header, and do not append a header if none is present.
```

By changing this to `PASS_THROUGH`, Envoy won't add this header.

To address the scenario when the backend service adds this header, use the [Route's](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#config-route-v3-route) `response_headers_to_remove` field.

Comment: how change HTTPConnectionManager settings to PASS_THROUGH ?

Answer (score 0):

Envoy adds the `server` header by itself to the response, so it seem to be impossible by `response_headers_to_remove`.
You can also refer to the [envoy/issues/14421](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/14421) which is the same question and one possible workaround was mentioned.